# Why do spectral lines in a series get closer together with increasing frequency?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I thought it would be the other way around, that closer spectral lines meant that the frequency was decreasing and wavelength was increasing. Why is this not the case?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the energy level diagram of hydrogen you will note that the energy levels get closer together as the energy increases.
Note that this diagram is from a website where the energies are given in kilojoules per mole.

[image]

This means for the Lyman series where the electron ends up in the $n=1$ state the difference in energy and hence frequency between the

$n=2$ to $n=1$ transition and the $n=3$ to $n=1$ transition ($= 328-146 = 182$ kJ)

is greater than the

$n=3$ to $n=1$ transition and the $n=4$ to $n=1$ transition ($= 146-82 = 64$ kJ).

Answer (score -1):

Because the energy difference between the levels increases and hence the wavelength difference decreases